# unable to use serialize-error package In nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to use the serialize-error package in the nodejs project, but received an error as shown in the screenshot attached :
[image]

my tsconfig.json file is as below,Please guide further what can I do for resolve this issue
"compilerOptions": {

```
"outDir": "dist",                       
"rootDir": "src",
 "target": "es5",                               
 "lib": ["ES6",],                                  
 "allowJs": false,                             
 "experimentalDecorators": true,                  
 "module": "commonjs",                               
 "moduleResolution": "node",                      
 "resolveJsonModule": true,                        
 "esModuleInterop": true,                             
"strict": true,
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by using the old version of this library. I was using its latest version. but its old version working now.